# Plot two fourier coeficients with python

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, scipy

I am working with the discrete Fourier transform in python. In my python code, how can I plot two Fourier coefficients in the complex plane.

I have seen that in matlab they use the following code to do it, they use dsearchn to plot it, as show here:

```
% create the signal
srate  = 1000; % hz
time   = 0:1/srate:2; % time vector in seconds
pnts   = length(time); % number of time points
signal = 2.5 * sin( 2*pi*4*time ) ...
       + 1.5 * sin( 2*pi*6.5*time );

% prepare the Fourier transform
fourTime = (0:pnts-1)/pnts;
fCoefs   = zeros(size(signal));

% compute frequencies vector
hz = linspace(0,srate/2,floor(pnts/2)+1);

%% plot two Fourier coefficients

coefs2plot = dsearchn(hz',[4 4.5]');

% extract magnitude and angle
mag = abs(fCoefs(coefs2plot));
phs = angle(fCoefs(coefs2plot));

figure(2), clf
plot( real(fCoefs(coefs2plot)) , imag(fCoefs(coefs2plot)) ,'o','linew',2,'markersize',10,'markerfacecolor','r');

% make plot look nicer
axislims = max(mag)*1.1;
set(gca,'xlim',[-1 1]*axislims,'ylim',[-1 1]*axislims)
grid on, hold on, axis square
plot(get(gca,'xlim'),[0 0],'k','linew',2)
plot([0 0],get(gca,'ylim'),'k','linew',2)
xlabel('Real axis')
ylabel('Imaginary axis')
title('Complex plane')
```

I've been told that I can use the package from scipy: **scipy.spatial.cKDTree**, but I don't know how to implement it in a python code taking the example from the matlab code.
Can anyone help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The plot commands below may not be very elegant, but I hope I'm getting what you are looking for. The 'dsearchn' usage has nothing to do with the Fourier transform, but is looking for the large features. If you plot the whole spectrum as I did you can find those features visually. In images 2-6 the y-axis is the title, and the x-axis is the frequency in Hz.

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as p
from ipywidgets import *

from numpy.fft import * 

# create the signal
srate  = 1000 # Hz   
numsec=1 
time   = np.linspace(0,numsec,srate*numsec+1) # time vector in seconds

signal = 2.5 * np.sin( 2*np.pi*4*time ) + 1.5 * np.sin( 2*np.pi*6.5*time );

p.figure(figsize=(14,6))
p.subplot(241)
p.plot(time,signal,'.-',lw=1,ms=2)
p.title('signal')

#  compute frequencies 
fourier = np.fft.fft(signal)
n = signal.size
timestep = 1/srate
freq = np.fft.fftfreq(n, d=timestep)

p.subplot(242)
p.plot(freq,np.abs(fourier),'.-',ms=2,lw=0.5)
p.plot(freq[4],np.abs(fourier[4]),'.-',ms=15 )
p.plot(freq[6],np.abs(fourier[6]),'.-',ms=15 )
p.title('full spectrum (abs)')

p.subplot(243)
p.plot(freq[:20],np.abs(fourier)[:20],'.-')
p.plot(freq[4],np.abs(fourier[4]),'.-',ms=15 )
p.plot(freq[6],np.abs(fourier[6]),'.-',ms=15 )
p.title('zoomed in (abs)')

p.subplot(244)
p.plot(freq[:20],np.angle(fourier)[:20],'.-')
p.plot(freq[4],np.angle(fourier[4]),'.-',ms=15 )
p.plot(freq[6],np.angle(fourier[6]),'.-',ms=15 )
p.title('zoomed in (phase)')

p.subplot(245)
p.plot(freq[:20],np.real(fourier)[:20],'.-')
p.plot(freq[4],np.real(fourier[4]),'.-',ms=15 )
p.plot(freq[6],np.real(fourier[6]),'.-',ms=15 )
p.title('zoomed in (real)')

p.subplot(246)
p.plot(freq[:20],np.imag(fourier)[:20],'.-')
p.plot(freq[4],np.imag(fourier[4]),'.-',ms=15 )
p.plot(freq[6],np.imag(fourier[6]),'.-',ms=15 )
p.title('zoomed in (imag)')

p.subplot(248)
p.plot(np.real(fourier)[:50],np.imag(fourier)[:50],'.')
p.plot(np.real(fourier[4]),np.imag(fourier[4]),'.',ms=15 )
p.plot(np.real(fourier[6]),np.imag(fourier[6]),'.',ms=15 )
p.xlabel('real axis')
p.ylabel('imag.axis')
p.title('complex plane')
```

[image: e]